# How can I add shadow to a view that has round corner and solid border?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am writing a "CardView" component that has a round corner and solid border, and I want it to display shadow when it is tapped. The code is shown below. It looks fine first, but when I actually tapped it, I found that the shadow is shown behind a rectangle that wraps the cards, rather than the card itself.

Why does this happen, and how can I solve it?

P.S. I want to let the view that uses `CardView` to add shadow to it , and the `CardView` itself shouldn't have any logic other than displaying the content, borders and round corner.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var cardState = CardState()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            let cardView = CardView(text: "Hello, world").onTapGesture {
                cardState.isSelected.toggle()
            }
            if cardState.isSelected {
                cardView.background(Color.white.shadow(radius: 6))
            } else {
                cardView
            }
        }.padding(20)
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
    private(set) var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            let rect = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            rect.fill().foregroundColor(.white)
            rect.strokeBorder(.blue, lineWidth: 2)
            
            Text(text).font(.system(.largeTitle))
        }
    }
}

class CardState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isSelected = false
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have declared a function to handle stroking and clipping:

```
public extension View {

    /// Clips a View to given `Shape` and traces the outline with a line in the given `Color`
    func outlined<S>(
        with shape: S,
        in color: Color,
        lineWidth: CGFloat
    ) -> some View where S: Shape {
        clipShape(shape)
            .overlay(
                shape.stroke(color, lineWidth: lineWidth))
            .contentShape(shape)
    }
}
```

so then you can simply define your views like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject private var cardState = CardState()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CardView(text: "Hello, world")
                .shadow(radius: cardState.isSelected ? 6 : 0)
                .onTapGesture {
                    cardState.isSelected.toggle()
                }
        }
        .padding(20)
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
    
    private(set) var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text(text).font(.system(.largeTitle))
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(Color.white)
        .outlined(
            with: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20),
            in: .blue,
            lineWidth: 2
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: But this also makes the texts inside the `CardView` has shadow, which is not what I expect.

Comment: Please see the edited view